# No files matched the search pattern while running azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, cicd

```
2022-11-01T06:29:24.0056480Z ##[section]Starting: Restore
2022-11-01T06:29:24.0268673Z ==============================================================================
2022-11-01T06:29:24.0269126Z Task         : .NET Core
2022-11-01T06:29:24.0269399Z Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
2022-11-01T06:29:24.0269645Z Version      : 2.210.0
2022-11-01T06:29:24.0269827Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-11-01T06:29:24.0270096Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
2022-11-01T06:29:24.0270389Z ==============================================================================
2022-11-01T06:29:25.9026573Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2022-11-01T06:29:25.9181132Z Active code page: 65001
2022-11-01T06:29:25.9204425Z Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
2022-11-01T06:29:26.4211886Z ##[error]No files matched the search pattern.
2022-11-01T06:29:26.4235445Z Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
2022-11-01T06:29:26.4308406Z ##[section]Finishing: Restore
```

I am new to this. trying to learn how to build a pipeline and thereby implement CICD.but facing this issues in Restore. Can some one help me with this?

Comment: For starters post some code and explain what you are trying to do and what you expect.

Comment: Typically I need to sprinkle things like this in my YAML to debug and work out where on earth my files are `      - task: CmdLine@2        inputs:          script: DIR $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) /B /S`

Comment: Hi Pratik, any update of this issue, have you checked my answer, does it answer your question? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need exact specific paths or an example that can be used directly in your case, be sure to re-edit your question and add your pipeline definition (YAML or JSON format) and repo structure.

Since you didn't provide the YAML file and repository structure. I will provide a common solution to solve the issue you encountered.

I notice the step you are running is restore.

I can reproduce your issue and I can solve the issue.

[image]

(Same issue as yours.)

For example,

this is the repository structure on my side:

[image]

So in build pipeline, you first can use the hardcoded to set the project section of the inputs of DotNetCoreCLI@2:

`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults/TestResults.sln`

My YAML definition:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults/TestResults.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '1f64a82f-77ad-4770-a098-772faae01ed1'
```

This usage should always work, by default, the content of repository will be check out to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`(This is [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services) in DevOps pipeline).

The above is for build pipeline, if you are using release pipeline, there is a artifact name path.

You can use dir in windows OS or ls in linux OS to check where your .csproj file are.